# What is the right syntax for args in Django 1.10?

Tags: python, django

I started to study Django 1.10, but it uses examples made on 1.6. That's why I have trouble with syntax in the new version.

This is my function:

```
def article(request, article_id=1):
    comment_form = CommentForm
    @csrf_protect
    args = {}
    args['article'] = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    args['comments'] = Comments.objects.filter(comments_artile_id=article_id)
    args['form'] = comment_form
return render (request, 'articles.html', args)
```

And my Traceback:

```
File "/home/goofy/djangoenv/bin/firstapp/article/views.py", line 30

args = {}      
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please show me what is the right syntax or where I can find the answer, because I can't find any explanations in the Django Docs.

Comment: Try to put `@csrf_protect` above the function.

Comment: You are right, it was a mistake. Thank you

Comment: @AlexeyG Welcome to StackOverflow! If your problem has been solved, please choose an answer to mark accepted and upvote any you found helpful. This helps people who come later to know which answers are the most helpful, and also rewards those who went out of their way to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`@csrf_protect` is a [python decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators). Put it above the method definition in order to work. 
Also, the `return` statement have to be indented like the rest of the method body.

```
@csrf_protect
def article(request, article_id=1):
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    args = {}
    args['article'] = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    args['comments'] = Comments.objects.filter(comments_artile_id=article_id)
    args['form'] = comment_form
    return render (request, 'articles.html', args)
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF Protect is ON by default, and if you want to use the decorator, you need to put it before the method like the [documentation say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#module-django.views.decorators.csrf).

Your `CommentForm` is an object in your forms.py (I suppose) you need to call him like that `CommentForm()`

```
@csrf_protect
def article(request, article_id=1):
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    args = {}
    args['article'] = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    args['comments'] = Comments.objects.filter(comments_artile_id=article_id)
    args['form'] = comment_form
    return render (request, 'articles.html', args)
```

But you can do it easier, Django create a dict with the related name example : `{{ article }}` in the template.html and the name of the object/variable in your wiews.py `a` ( who is `Comments.objects.filter(comments_artile_id=article_id)`).

```
@csrf_protect
def article(request, article_id=1):
    form = CommentForm()
    a = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    c = Comments.objects.filter(comments_artile_id=article_id)
    return render (request, 'articles.html', {
                'article': a,
                'comments': c,
                'comment_form': form})
```